# Check length and auto insert character Stored Procedures SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a requirement as below:

```
SELECT code from Products
```

- Select code to table Products
- Check length of code; if < 8 auto insert "0" before it to enough 8 character.

Sample:

```
If code is : 1234  => 00001234
             12345 => 00012345
             ..... => xxxxxxxx
```

I want to use a stored procedures in SQL Server 2012 to do it.

Comment: You can refer to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19947878/sql-server-how-to-create-a-stored-procedure) on how to create a stored procedure and to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760900/pad-a-string-with-leading-zeros-so-its-3-characters-long-in-sql-server-2008) on how to pad a string with leading zeros up to certain character long.

Comment: You should be able to do this as an `UPDATE` statement, or even changing it into a trigger.  Although I'm more worried about the fact that you're prepending zeros - it likely means there's something screwy with how you're using this field...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the `CODE` field is string, this will work

```
SELECT RIGHT('00000000'+ISNULL(CODE,''),8) from Products
```

If `CODE` is integer then

```
 SELECT RIGHT('00000000'+CAST(CODE AS VARCHAR(8)),8) from Products
```

Comment: This answer has using for mask text in sql. Very useful!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN LEN(code) < 8 THEN REPLICATE('0', 8 - LEN(code)) + code
        ELSE code
    END
FROM Products
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this.

1. Use function "CONCAT" your numbers with 000000000 .
2. Use function "RIGHT" to show 8 digits from right to left .

`select right(CONCAT('000000000', 1234),8) as xxx`

Hope its help.

Comment: 'CONCAT' is not a recognized function in sql server.

Comment: Sorry i'm trying this code in sql2014.  - -!